# UnionFind datastructure

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am attempting to solve the following questions - [The Earliest Moment When Everyone Become Friends](https://leetcode.com/problems/the-earliest-moment-when-everyone-become-friends/description/)

> There are n people in a social group labeled from 0 to n - 1. You are
> given an array logs where logs[i] = [timestampi, xi, yi] indicates
> that xi and yi will be friends at the time timestampi.
>
> Friendship is symmetric. That means if a is friends with b, then b is
> friends with a. Also, person a is acquainted with a person b if a is
> friends with b, or a is a friend of someone acquainted with b.
>
> Return the earliest time for which every person became acquainted with
> every other person. If there is no such earliest time, return -1.

I am trying to do so using a UnionFind where in order to find the earliest moment, I combined/union edges until the number of components are 1 as in they all have the same root node but I don't receive the right answer always. Initially start of with 'n' different components and if a union is possible, I reduce the number of components.

Is this the wrong approach? Can anyone offer some advice on what would be wrong with the code?

```
public class EarliestMomentFriends {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][]logs = {{20190101,0,1},{20190104,3,4},{20190107,2,3},{20190211,1,5},
                {20190224,2,4},{20190301,0,3},{20190312,1,2},{20190322,4,5}};
        int n = 6;
        EarliestMomentFriends emf = new EarliestMomentFriends();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(emf.earliestAcq2(logs, n));
    }
    
    public int earliestAcq2(int[][]logs, int n) {
        //sort the logs in ascending order
        Arrays.sort(logs, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(int[]a, int[]b) {
                return Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]);
            }
        });
        UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(n);
        for(int pos = 0; pos < logs.length; pos++) {
            int[] log = logs[pos];
            if(!uf.isConnected(log[1], log[2])) {
                int comps = uf.union(log[1], log[2]);
                if(comps == 1) {
                    return log[0];
                }
            }
            
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
    
    class UnionFind{
        public int[] root;
        public int[] rank;
        int components;
        
        private UnionFind(int n) {
            root = new int[n];
            rank = new int[n];
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                root[i] = i;
                rank[i] = 1;
            }
            components = n;
        }
        
        private int find(int x) {
            if(root[x] == x) {
                return x;
            }
            return find(root[x]);
        }
        
        private int union(int x, int y) {
            int rootX = find(x);
            int rootY = find(y);
            if(rootX != rootY) {
                if(rank[rootX] > rank[rootY]) {
                    root[y] = rootX;
                }
                else if(rank[rootY] > rank[rootX]) {
                    root[x] = rootY;
                }
                else {
                    root[y] = rootX;
                    rank[rootX]++;
                }
                components--;
            }
            return components;
        }
        
        private boolean isConnected(int x, int y) {
            return find(x) == find(y);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your logic is ok, but you have a bug when making one node the root of another. Instead of doing `root[y] = ...` or `root[x] = ...`, use the parent nodes calculated, not the parameter nodes.